# Last xml tag not ended in xmlparser

Tags: php, xml-parsing

Hullo,
I bounced in a very strange problem: a restricted set of results to an http request like:
http://www.miafoto.it/iPhone/inarrivo/php/percorsoWithOption.php?partenza=Via%20Ugolino%20Vivaldi&arrivo=Via%20Della%20Corazzata&language=it&userLatitude=41.719070&userLongitude=12.311775
producing the xml code you may easily read, never reach the didEndElement callback in its parser for just the last pathway tag.
The result of other urls like:
http://www.miafoto.it/iPhone/inarrivo/php/percorsoWithOption.php?partenza=Via%20Ugolino%20Vivaldi&arrivo=Via%20Conca%20D'oro&language=it&userLatitude=41.719074&userLongitude=12.311768
like many others, get instead correctly terminated with the last pathway tag so returning a usable array differently of the non closing parsing.
What is really strange is that the structure of the xml outputs are quite similar being produced by the same php script. What could make the difference and how to have either the php script or the xmlparser produce a reliable behavior?
Thanks.

Comment: One problem was that I sent a notification when the data was ready that was received both by the controller opening the viewController and by the viewController itself; what possibly produced a data corruption. Yet the problem resists and what is strange is that it presents itself more often on the iPhone than on the simulator hinting to a nasty memory problem.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem was in the php script for reasons yet unclear as in one case a tag was inside another and in the other reverse.